# Firestoreで ドキュメントID と フィールドの OR 検索は可能でしょうか。

Tags: node.js, firebase

### 質問

Firebase SDK を利用して、Firestoreのクエリを作成しています。
・ドキュメントIDの完全一致
・フィールド1つの完全一致
これらのクエリを使ってOR検索するにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

公式doc を見てみましたが、具体的な内容が見つかりませんでした。

### 調査詳細

下記のようなコードを作りました。

```
await getDocs(
  query(
    colRef,
    or(
      where(documentId(), "==", "foo"),
      where("name", "==", "bar"),
    )
  )
)
```

向き先を Firestore エミュレータに設定して実行すると成功しますが、
実際の Firestore に対して実行すると、下記のエラーが表示されます。

```
FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/****
```

このリンクをクリックしてFirebaseにアクセスすると下記が表示されます。

| フィールド | オーダー | ステータス |
| --- | --- | --- |
| __name__ | 昇順 | 作成が必要 |

ここで、「作成」ボタンをクリックすると下記のエラー表示。

```
__name__ only indexes are not supported
```

手動で複合インデックスを作成しようと下記のように入力

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name | Ascending |
| 2 | __name__ | Ascending |

これで「インデックスを作成」ボタンをクリックすると下記のエラー表示。

```
this index is not necessary, configure using single field index controls
```

### 環境

```
"firebase": "^10.3.1",
```

```
❯ node --version
v18.17.1
```